# Unexpected nil when initialising Integer with Double

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand what's happening in the following scenarios:

```swift
let input: [Double] = [2.3]
// scenario 1
input.compactMap { Int.init($0) } // [2]
// scenario 2
input.compactMap(Int.init) // []
```

Scenario 1 gives an array containing `2`, as expected. The `Double` is rounded, and converted to an `Int`. Scenario 2 however gives an empty array, as the given `Double` is apparently not convertible to an `Int`.

Can someone explain what's happening here? I'd expected both scenarios to give the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer by inspecting the different `.init` methods.

In scenario 1 the following initialiser is used:

```swift
init(_ source: Double)
```

whilst in scenario 2 this initialiser is used:

```swift
init?(exactly source: Double)
```

My expectation was that the same initialiser would be used here, as I've given no label to indicate that I'm referring to another initialiser. I guess this + the combination of using a `compactMap` makes swift prefer the initialiser used in scenario 2, as using a normal `map` instead of a `compactMap` produces the expected result.

The fix for now is to explicitly state that I want to use the initialiser from scenario 1:

```swift
input.compactMap(Int.init(_:)) // [2]
```

Comment: Just to complete your answer, Swift uses the initializer that best matches the type of the parameter, and `compactMap` expect a closure that returns an Optional (`init?(exactly:)` is failable and returns an optional)